# ICO tokens arrived back to address from which I sent ETH, but they won't load in wallet

Tags: etherscan, ico

I could use some help. I bought an ICO. Sent ETH to the ICO. The ICO sent back  tokens to the same address.

Etherscan proved it, including an overview that stated smart contract was executed.

HOWEVER, I still have a miniscule amount of ETH in the wallet from which I sent payment, like $2. So obviously, the ICO token won't load into the wallet.

How do I empty the wallet of ETH, so the ICO token can load and this disaster is done, and then how do I load the wallet once it's empty (beyond refreshing the wallet, if there's more).

I'll take links for instructions if it saves time. Not my first crypto purchase. Just my first ICO purchase.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Which wallet are you using ? Normally you need to tell your wallet to follow the token you purchased. You do this by selecting the option to add custom token, pasting the token contract ( usually the same as the crowdsale contract ).

Also you dont need to deplete your wallet of all ether to show your other token balances.